# Trying to make an image classification model using AutoML Vision run on a website

Tags: tensorflow.js, google-cloud-automl

I've created a classification model using AutoML Vision and tried to use [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tensorflow-js-tutorial?_ga=2.245966400.-55487651.1648514707&_gac=1.61854174.1648905034.Cj0KCQjw6J-SBhCrARIsAH0yMZhG7bXhnNscFr09VIp9bK3x70O9dGFC2U-ZIHn3ZMtaW7FlOIQJ8E8aAk0_EALw_wcB) to make a small web app to make the model classify an image using the browser.
The code I'm using is basically the same as the tutorial with some slight changes:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-automl"></script>
<img id="test" crossorigin="anonymous" src="101_SI_24_23-01-2019_iOS_1187.JPG">
<script>
async function run() {
  const model = await tf.automl.loadImageClassification('model.json');
  const image = document.getElementById('test');
  const predictions = await model.classify(image);
  console.log(predictions);
  // Show the resulting object on the page.
  const pre = document.createElement('pre');
  pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(predictions, null, 2);
  document.body.append(pre);
}
```

run();

This index.html file above is located in the same folder of the model files and the image file. The problem is that when I try to run the file I'm receiving this error:
[error received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN4zj.png)

I have no idea what I should do to fix this error. I've tried many things without success, I've only changed the error.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue and I filed a bug on the [TensorFlow.js repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6720). In the future, I suggest you post on the [TensorFlow forum](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/) since TensorFlow team members tend to monitor it. Also feel free to file bugs and feature requests on GitHub. Thank you for bringing this issue to our attention! -Jen Person, Developer Advocate, TensorFlow

Answer (score 0):

models built with AutoML should not have dynamic ops, but seems that yours does.

if that is truly model designed using AutoML, then AutoML should be expanded to use asynchronous execution.

if model was your own (not AutoML), it would be a simple `await model.executeAsync()` instead of `model.execute()`, but in AutoML case, that part is hidden inside AutoML library module inside `classify` call and that needs to be addressed by tfjs AutoML team.

best to open an issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues

btw, why post a link to an image containing error message instead of copying the message as text here??